# Точка после номера параграфа

Tags: заголовок, перечисление

Нужна ли точка после номера параграфа в заголовке (при использовании значка параграфа)?
§ 6 УЧЕНИЕ... или § 6. УЧЕНИЕ...
В правилах-гостах не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Порядковый номер параграфа (в учебной и справочной литературе со знаком **§**) надо писать в строку с его названием, **отделяя точкой.**
[Слово о рубрикации](https://compuart.ru/article/18122)

Вот ТАК "оформлен" [справочник Д. Э. Розенталя](http://rosental-book.ru/):

**II.** Правописание согласных в корне
**§ 8.** Звонкие и глухие согласные
**§ 9.** Двойные согласные в корне и на стыке приставки и корня
**§ 10.** Непроизносимые согласные